# Ffmpeg does not properly convert videos when run as daemon

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-daemon

I'm using ffmpeg to convert and split videos from a Python process. When I run it from console as a normal user everything works as expected, however, if I run it as a daemon it produces the same amount of files but with silence in almost the whole file.

This is the line I execute from python:

```
def convert_to_ffmpeg(file, ffmpeg_folder, chunk_length):
    res = -1
    try:
        file_name = os.path.join(ffmpeg_folder, ntpath.basename(file) + ".flac")
        res = os.system("ffmpeg -i " + file + " -f segment -segment_time "+str(chunk_length)+" " + file_name + " -y  >/dev/null 2>&1")
    except Exception as e:
        raise MyException(code=210005, detalails=file, cause=e)
    if not res == 0:
        raise MyException(code=210004, detalails=str(res) + " - " + file)
    return file_name
```

When I run it from a normal console it works as expected: it splits the video in chunks of  "self._chunk_length" seconds.

However, if I run the program using python-daemon with this code:

```
if daemon_run:
    pid_file = check_unclean_exit(config['pidfile'], log)

    context = daemon.DaemonContext(
        working_directory=approot,
        umask=0o002,
        pidfile=pid_file,
    )
    context.signal_map = {
        signal.SIGTERM: programa_cleanup,
        signal.SIGHUP: 'terminate',
        # signal.SIGUSR1: reload_program_config,
    }

    with context:
        convert_to_ffmpeg("/foo/testfile.mkv", "/foo/ffmpeg", 40)
```

It produces EXACTLY the same chunks, however, most of the content of the chunks is just silence. It splits in the proper point, but doesn't fill the contents of the audio output properly. Of course, no exception is thrown, as ffmpeg always returns 0

I did even install a completly fresh Debian 9 into a virtual machine to discard problems with ffmpeg and my old-good computer's setup.

Of course this is a simplified example. The real thing is a multithread application which watches a directory for files to convert.

Comment: Discarding all the output, including error messages, is terrible for troubleshooting.

Comment: I know, but output outside debug environment is useless using os.system, and using a more compolet process manager seems a waste provided the console output is unnecesary when you have the error code. FFMpeg failing returning 0 IS A STRANGE SITUATION that should not happen to my understanding. Nevertheless, outputting to a file gives an "everything is OK" output, while still destroying videos.