# ffmpeg errors in the daemon

Tags: python, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I created a shell script to compress a video using ffmpeg(4.3.1).

```
ffmpeg -y -i \
 '/var/www/System/Backend/Outputs/TempSaveMovie/200703_4_short_5fr_p2(100_20)_r(50_20).mp4' \
 -vcodec h264 -an \
 '/var/www/System/Backend/Outputs/MovieOutputs/200703_4_short_5fr_p2(100_20)_r(50_20).mp4'
```

If you run this code from the console, it will run without problems.
In fact, we're using the python `subscript.call()` to execute it. It works fine too.

```
cmd = 'sh /var/www/System/Backend/cv2toffmpeg.sh'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Secondly, if I run it from a daemonized python program, I'll get an error. I get the following error.
You'll get an error like this

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './Outputs/TempSaveMovie/200703_4_short_5fr_p2(100_20)_r(50_20).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10246 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10244 kb/s, 13 fps, 13 tbr, 13312 tbn, 13 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c5480] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c6840] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec1855f80] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec1866e00] header damaged
Output #0, mp4, to './Outputs/MovieOutputs/200703_4_short_5fr_p2(100_20)_r(50_20).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 13 fps, 13312 tbn, 13 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 4000000 vbv_delay: N/A
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c8780] header damaged
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mpeg4 @ 0x55cec17c5480] header damaged
```

I think the problem is when you run it from a daemonized process. There seems to be a similar problem in the past.
[Ffmpeg does not properly convert videos when run as daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276880/ffmpeg-does-not-properly-convert-videos-when-run-as-daemon)
I would like to ask for your help to solve this problem. Thank you for your help from Japan.

Comment: check this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222847/how-to-stream-with-ffmpeg-in-a-separate-process) may be useful

Comment: very thanks, i solve this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Add  `-nostdin` option. This option clear the problem.